# can I use Tomtom Live traffic as Web Part in my Sharepoint 2013 Site?

Tags: sharepoint, maps, sharepoint-2013

I want to use ** [Houston TranStar Traffic Map](http://traffic.houstontranstar.org/layers/)** as a **Traffic web part** for my **SharePoint 2013 site**.

is it possible?

Or can I use any other better service for the same like  **Tom Tom web site Live Traffic feed** ?

if No, can anybody provide me any other solution with reference link ?

Please don't answer for **Google maps** as My client looking for its **alternative**

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Is an Iframe an alternative? You can just embed the Houston page via a "[Page Viewer WebPart](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-server-help/page-viewer-web-part-HA010024045.aspx)". Very quick solution and shows you the map.